# Removing single quotes,commas

Tags: string, list, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have list which content the following words.

```
      word_list = ['Here', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what', 'I', 'am',
                   'working', 'with', 'But', 'I', 'need', 'to', 'change', 'the format',
                   'to', 'something', 'more', 'useable']
```

i would like to this format

```
     word_list = [Here is an example of what I am
                    working with But I need to change the format 
                    to something more useable]
```

**Is it possible to achieve that? How can I concatenate the words in the list?**

I tried for this code. but I achieves a list of words instead of a sentence.

```
  blog_posts=[]
  stop = stopwords.words('english')+[
   '.',
   ',',
   '--',
   '\'s',
    '?',
    ')',
   '(',
   ':',
  '\'',
   '\'re',
  '"',
  '-',
  '}',
  '{',
  u'—',
 'a', 'able', ]
 file=open("resources/ch05-webpages/newspapers/25314/Indexpress111.csv","r+")
 #resources\ch05-webpages\newspapers\midday11.csv
 #t=[i for i in file.read().split() if i not in stop]
 t=    [i.replace("'","").replace("?","").replace(":","").replace("\"","").replace("\'","").strip() 

for i in file.read().split() if i not in stop]
 blog_posts.append((t,))
print blog_posts
```

Comment: `so give me proper solution` ask nicely

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Python syntax. You also forgot to post the code you tried.

Comment: @timcastelijns, lolz... okay, let's play nice and answer his question properly =)

Comment: @alvas before the edit there wasn't even a question mark, i found that pretty rude

Comment: @timcastelijns, now i see =), yeah. let me edit the question to a nicer tone.

Comment: I think someone's also working on the same course... It looks like your code is from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576781/how-to-remove-quotes-after-removing-stopwords-from-nltk) with a bit added from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576781/how-to-remove-quotes-after-removing-stopwords-from-nltk/22585730#22585730)... Perhaps you and Prashant should point out to the instructor that the course is really very unclear if you're both having to ask the same question? :p

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `word_list` is a list. If you want to output the concatenated words as a string, you can use `str.join(list)`, see [Explain Python .join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join). I would assume your required output is a string that is printable to console or writable to a file, so you can try:

```
>>> word_list = ['Here', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what', 'I', 'am',
...                    'working', 'with', 'But', 'I', 'need', 'to', 'change', 'the format',
...                    'to', 'something', 'more', 'useable']
>>> 
>>> print " ".join(word_list)
Here is an example of what I am working with But I need to change the format to something more useable
```

If the previous paragraph seem alien to you, then I suggest you go through some basics in python and then come back to the code snippet above to understand it, try http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python